# Using drupal 7 commerce feeds, how can I import the node reference images?

Tags: commerce, media, feeds

I have followed [the drupal commerce guide](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/importing-products-using-feeds) All of my products have been imported and show up in the store. When I attempt to import the Product Reference's everything is good except the images won't show up. Can someone point me in the right direction ?